# Is it a WinAPI Bug with PathIsRelative function?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(VS.85).aspx#fully_qualified_vs._relative_paths), a path of `C:tmp.txt` should be considered as relative, but `PathIsRelative()` returns `FALSE` instead of `TRUE`.

Is this a bug? Or am I mistaken somewhere?

Comment: Why does it confuse you that `PathIsRelative` returns `true` for a relative path? You even state that in your question.

Comment: It was clearly a typo that you wrote `TRUE` in the original post. I edited the question to correct the mistake. For the sake of clarity then, I confirm that `PathIsRelative("C:tmp.txt")` does indeed return `FALSE`.

Comment: @David Heffernan thanks for your corrections.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends what is meant by relative. A path like `C:tmp.txt` is quite special. It is relative to the current directory on drive C. On the other hand, `tmp.txt` is relative to the process current directory. Which may not be on drive C. In fact, per-drive current directories are also rather special, being implemented by means of some curious environment variables purely as a way to preserve some compatibility with DOS. More on this rather arcane subject can be found in Raymond Chen's article: [Why does each drive have its own current directory?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/10/11/10073890.aspx)

It would appear that `PathIsRelative` takes a different view from you as to what a relative path is. The `PathIsRelative` function does not regard a path that is relative to the working directory on a specified drive to be a relative path. Hence `PathIsRelative("C:tmp.txt")` returns `FALSE`. If you want a function that will treat such a path as being relative you will likely have to write it yourself. It is pretty easy to parse the path by hand to detect this scenario.

Comment: For example, [`ntdll!RtlDetermineDosPathNameType_U`](http://svn.reactos.org/svn/reactos/tags/ReactOS-0.3.16/reactos/lib/rtl/path.c?view=markup#l1296) returns the [`RTL_PATH_TYPE`](http://svn.reactos.org/svn/reactos/tags/ReactOS-0.3.16/reactos/include/ndk/rtltypes.h?view=markup#l428), i.e. UNC (`\\Server\C$\Windows`), drive absolute (`C:\Windows`), drive relative (`C:Windows`), rooted (`\Windows`), relative (`Windows`), or a local device path (`\\.\Pipe` or `\\?\GlobalRoot\SystemRoot`). Just roll your own and build `PathIsRelative` on top of it.